# Lagrangian optimisation problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, lagrange-multiplier, economics

If labour $L > 0$ and capital $K > 0$ and they are used to produce 2 goods (**1** and **2**) so we have

$$ L = l_1 + l_2 , $$
$$ K = k_1 + k_2 , $$

and all $l_i$ and $k_i$ are non-negative. Production function of each goods is given by

$$ q_i = \sqrt{l_i * k_i} .$$

---

The question is how can I set up a parametric constrained Lagrangian function to maximize $q_2$ with parameter $q_1$, $L$, $K$? More specifically, what should the constraint be?

Cheers!

Comment: The Langrangian function is $$\textrm{max}_{l_2, k_2} \ \ q_1(l_1,k_1)+\sqrt{l_2\cdot k_2}+\lambda_1(L-l_1-l_2)+\lambda_2(K-k_1-k_2)$$

Comment: ^That is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

The objective function is given by $\sqrt{l_2k_2}$. Let $q_1$ denote some fixed quantity of good $1$. The equality constraints are:
$$\begin{align*}l_1+l_2&=L\\
k_1+k_2&=K\\
\sqrt{l_1k_1}&=q_1\end{align*}$$

The problem is (ignoring the non-negativity constraints):
$$\max_{l_1,l_2,k_1,k_2} \sqrt{l_2k_2}\qquad \text{subject to $\qquad \begin{align*}l_1+l_2&=L\\k_1+k_2&=K\\\sqrt{l_1k_1}&=q_1\end{align*}$}$$

The Lagrangian is given by
$$\sqrt{k_2l_2}+\lambda_L(L-l_1-l_2)+\lambda_K(K-k_1-k_2)+\lambda(q_1-\sqrt{l_1k_1}).$$

Alternatively, if we substitute for $l_1$ and $k_1$ using the first two constraints, then we can write the problem as
$$\max_{l_2,k_2} \sqrt{l_2k_2}\qquad \text{subject to $\qquad \sqrt{(L-l_2)(K-k_2)}=q_1$}$$
for which the Lagrangian is

$$\sqrt{k_2l_2}+\lambda\left(q_1-\sqrt{(L-l_2)(K-k_2)}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

Solving the four equations as a function of $q_{1}$, $K$ and $L$, we obtain the relations:

$k_{1}=\frac{\sqrt{K}}{\sqrt{L}}q_{1}$,

$k_{2}=\frac{\sqrt{K}(\sqrt{K L}-q_{1})}
{\sqrt{L}}$,

$l_{1}=\frac{\sqrt{L}}{\sqrt{K}}q_{1}$,

$l_{2}=\frac{\sqrt{L}(\sqrt{K L}-q_{1})}{\sqrt{K}}$.

The function to be maximized becomes:

$q_2 = \sqrt{l_2 * k_2} =\sqrt{K L}-q_1$.